# How to force rewrite url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

If an user clicks on these links or write these links in the address bar, I would like to force rewriting.

Is it possible ?

`index.php?page=admin--index` to `admin/index`

...

`index.php?page=team--create` to `team/create`

Thanks

Comment: @Croises answer is correct and it solves the issue you described in your post, You should accept it so that your Questions doesnt show up in unanswered ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)--([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
```

And if you need in the other direction:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1--$2 [L]
```

Comment: Ok but it's only for admin and team, I have a lot of string which have the same structure such as: login--index, user--settings etc... etc...

Comment: Oh YAY!!! It works for that! But my CSS/JS doesn't work anymore... My CSS/JS is called by` css/style.css`, so if this, I have `login/css/style.css` and it doesn't found.

Comment: Use absolute links for css files or add `<base href="/">` in html head

Comment: It's the same problem with all relative links in the page or Javascript. Because you add one `/` level, the root "change". With `<base href="/">` or `<base href="http://domain.com/">` everything is relative to the root of the domain name.